# How does PFObject allow subscripting like NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, objective-c-literals

I was reading Parse's iOS Developers Guide.
I got confused where it shows `PFObject` assigning to keys with subscript syntax.

```
PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
gameScore[@"score"] = @1337;
gameScore[@"playerName"] = @"Sean Plott";
gameScore[@"cheatMode"] = @NO;


PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
gameScore[@"score"] = @1337;
```

First I thought that `PFObject` must be extending `NSMutableDictionary`, but `PFObject` is extending `NSObject` only. How it is behaving like `NSMutableDictionary`?

How can I do this for my own class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/) has the answer:

> Similarly, custom-keyed subscripting can be added to your class by declaring and implementing these methods:

```
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(*KeyType*)key;
- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(*KeyType*)key;
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for setting a key value is translated by the compiler into a call to the method `setObject:forKeyedSubscript` and will work with any class that provides such a method, not just `NSMutableDictionary`.

For full details read "Object Indexing" in the [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) section of the Clang compiler documentation.

HTH